# How to Bind to Static IP address in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an Ubuntu server and I've installed MySQL.  How would I use my two physical static IP addresses in `my.cnf` bind-address -- can I add two IP addresses?

Answer (score 6):

[Only one address can be specified](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address), but you can set bind-address to  0.0.0.0 in order to make MySQL listen on all available interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

As Adam said, use `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to get MySQL to listen to all IP addresses. This will ensure that it listens to bnoth static IP's you've got on the box.

If you have more than 2 static IP's and don't want MySQL listening on those ports, install a Firewall on your box and block off port `3306` to all but the two IP's you want using MySQL. That way your firewall handles the access control rather than MySQL.

Here is a "little" guide to set up the firewall:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055164/connection-to-mysql-server-in-syn-sent

Just look at the second part with the answer.